# how to get the value of a checked checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have a form like below:

```
   <form id="toppings_div" name="form1" method="post" action="">
                            <table width="355">
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  <input type="checkbox" value="Cheese" />
                                  <label>Extra cheese</label>
                                </td></tr></table></from>
```

I was just wondering how I can get to the value of the checkbox if it's checked.

thanks

```
        alert($('#toppings_div').children().children().children().children(':checked').val());
```

using the code above gives me an undefined answer,

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used the following line of code to solve my problem:

```
alert($('input:checked').val() );
```

Comment: This will get you the value of the **first** checked input on your page, make sure that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

$('#toppings_div input:checkbox:checked').val() is all that's needed. The > in the selector means direct descendant of.

Answer (score 0):

Try
    .checked()

Comment: There is no **function** `checked` in jQuery