# How to get a value of a CheckBox from td (table), JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a table with text data but in one cell I have a checkbox. I can extract data from td, but I can't figure out how to extract the checkbox value

Here's what I've tried (see attached picture!)

```
$('#tableData tbody tr:eq('+row+')').find('td:eq(8)').eq(0).value
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKM9sqBGY28cXp5ZzVCc0dRc28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the value of a checked checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259704/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-checked-checkbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#tableData tbody tr:eq('+row+')').find('td:eq(8) input').is(':checked')
```

Comment: `..is(':checked')` returns boolean not the value.

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox has 2 states. Checked and unchecked.

**To get the value use the .prop('value') - please see my JSFiddle at the bottom. (I also updated the example(s))**

I hope you are properly setting checked value on the control (from your code it is not clear if you're trying to set the value to something and expecting to see a checked checkbox or you're properly setting "checked" property.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckboxId" value="0"  checked>
```

In jquery use the selector to find the checkbox. Please search SO since there are so many examples. Looping with "row" as counter is not the best way, use .each on the table to look for rows with checked checkboxes.

Even with what you have add and ID to your control (checkbox):

```
var isChecked = $('#tableData tbody tr:eq('+row+')').find('myCheckboxId').is(':checked');
```

Or:

```
var isChecked = $('#tableData tbody tr:eq('+row+') input:checkbox').is(':checked');
var checkBoxValue = $('#tableData tbody tr:eq('+row+') input:checkbox').prop('value');
```

http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/ try there first.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/umdhrcs8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
$('#tableData tbody tr:eq('+row+') td:eq(8) input').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting the `td` element, instead the `input`, no? Try:

```
$('#tableData tbody tr:eq('+row+') td:eq(8) input').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could query for the checkbox itself. (Even better, give the checkbox a name or an ID and query for that.)

```js
alert($('input[type=checkbox]').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="99"></td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the checkbox at all in your query.

Try changing:

```
$('#tableData tbody tr:eq('+row+')').find('td:eq(8)').eq(0).value
```

To:

```
$('#tableData tbody tr:eq('+row+')').find('td:eq(8)').eq(0).find('checkbox').val();
```

Comment: `...find('checkbox')` won't return anything.

Comment: Just noticed i've removed .eq(0). Should be working now.

Comment: you are not getting it. it should be something like this `$('#tableData tbody tr:eq('+row+')').find('td:eq(8)').find('input').val()`